# Merge cells in excel depending on the value in another cell

Tags: worksheet-function, merge, cells

I'm looking to minimize the time required to input information in an Excel worksheet. I have a cell which can have the numbers 1, 2 OR 3 and depending on the value of that cell, I need some cells to merge and be ready for information to be input in them. Here's basically how it should end up looking:

**First case:**
[image]

**Second case:**
[image]

**Third case:**
[image]

We can do it manually (merge the cells together after we input the number), however, it does take away a lot of time. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? I'm guessing you'd need a macro to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was able to put together a macro that does this, basically:

Sub Funcion_Merge()

Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Range("Polos_impar")
    If cell.Value = 3 Then
    Range("H13:H15").Merge False
    End If
    Next cell
End Sub

So I was able to understand how the merge function works. Now, I'm trying to figure out how to tell excel what cells to merge. So for example:

If it finds that cell D13 is a 2, it needs to merge H13 and H14

If it finds that cell D24 is a 3, it needs to merge H24, H25 and H26. And so on

Comment: Cool. Post it here as an answer to your own question, to help out others who may try to do the same thing.